# Unable to build the image using the OpenShift build service: Timeout: request did not complete within 1m0s

Tags: syndesis

I'm trying to build Syndesis with the following command:

`syndesis build -m s2i -i -d -f -c --clean-cache`

But after building most of the projects, I got a final error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.5.38:build (exec) on project s2i:
>   Failed to execute the build: Unable to build the image using the
>   OpenShift build service: Failure executing: POST at:
>   https://192.168.42.58:8443/apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/syndesis/buildconfigs/syndesis-s2i-s2i/instantiatebinary?commit=.
>   Message: Timeout: request did not complete within 1m0s. Received
>   status: Status(apiVersion=meta/v1, code=504,
>   details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null, kind=null, name=null,
>   retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}),
>   kind=Status, message=Timeout: request did not complete within 1m0s,
>   metadata=ListMeta(resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null,
>   additionalProperties={}), reason=Timeout, status=Failure,
>   additionalProperties={}). -> [Help 1]

Full stacktrace:

```
Going to cache locally Syndesis 1.8-SNAPSHOT dependencies.
Installing Syndesis 1.8-SNAPSHOT dependencies to target directory...
This installation won't use a camel snapshot version
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- fabric8-maven-plugin:3.5.38:build (exec) @ s2i ---
[INFO] F8: Using OpenShift build with strategy Docker
[INFO] F8: Generators:
[INFO] F8:  - spring-boot
[INFO] F8:  - wildfly-swarm
[INFO] F8:  - karaf
[INFO] F8:  - vertx
[INFO] F8:  - java-exec
[INFO] F8:  - webapp
[INFO] Building tar: /var/git/syndesis/app/s2i/target/docker/syndesis/syndesis-s2i/latest/tmp/docker-build.tar
[INFO] F8: [syndesis/syndesis-s2i:latest]: Created docker source tar /var/git/syndesis/app/s2i/target/docker/syndesis/syndesis-s2i/latest/tmp/docker-build.tar
[INFO] F8: Updating BuildServiceConfig syndesis-s2i-s2i for Docker strategy
[INFO] F8: Adding to ImageStream syndesis-s2i
[INFO] F8: Enrichers:
[INFO] F8: - fmp-name
[INFO] F8: - fmp-controller
[INFO] F8: - fmp-service
[INFO] F8: - fmp-image
[INFO] F8: - fmp-portname
[INFO] F8: - fmp-ianaservice
[INFO] F8: - fmp-project
[INFO] F8: - fmp-dependency
[INFO] F8: - fmp-pod-annotations
[INFO] F8: - fmp-git
[INFO] F8: - fmp-debug
[INFO] F8: - fmp-merge
[INFO] F8: - fmp-remove-build-annotations
[INFO] F8: - fmp-volume-permission
[INFO] F8: - f8-cd
[INFO] F8: - f8-cd-doc-link
[INFO] F8: - f8-cd-grafana-link
[INFO] F8: - f8-icon
[INFO] F8: - f8-expose
[INFO] F8: - fmp-openshift-route
[INFO] F8: - spring-boot-health-check
[INFO] F8: - wildfly-swarm-health-check
[INFO] F8: - karaf-health-check
[INFO] F8: - vertx-health-check
[INFO] F8: - docker-health-check
[INFO] F8: - f8-prometheus
[INFO] F8: - f8-maven-scm
[INFO] F8: - f8-maven-issue-mgmt
[INFO] F8: - f8-watch
[INFO] F8: - fmp-revision-history
[INFO] F8: - fmp-docker-registry-secret
[INFO] F8: Starting Build syndesis-s2i-s2i
[ERROR] F8: OpenShift Error: [504 Failure] [Timeout] Timeout: request did not complete within 1m0s
[ERROR] F8: Failed to execute the build [Unable to build the image using the OpenShift build service]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:31 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-05T10:29:58+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/130M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.5.38:build (exec) on project s2i: Failed to execute the build: Unable to build the image using the OpenShift build service: Failure executing: POST at: https://192.168.42.58:8443/apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/syndesis/buildconfigs/syndesis-s2i-s2i/instantiatebinary?commit=. Message: Timeout: request did not complete within 1m0s. Received status: Status(apiVersion=meta/v1, code=504, details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null, kind=null, name=null, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=Timeout: request did not complete within 1m0s, metadata=ListMeta(resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=Timeout, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}). -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
ERROR: Last command exited with 1
```

Any hints where this may come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when the is either really slow to download artifacts from the Internet or can't download them. There should be an error pointing in that direction in the build pod log. Sometimes this is just an client side timeout, meaning that the build is still ongoing and it will finish eventually. If that's so, the image layers used in the build should be cached and the next build should take less time.

Comment: Yeah, that is typically the reason. However it should no longer happen with the recent change described here https://github.com/syndesisio/syndesis/pull/6296 as the docker is fed by local stored artifacts now.